# Microsoft Azure Machine Learning Studio from Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, python, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

Is there a way to use the same ML-realizations as used in Microsoft Azure Machine Learning Studio but on my computer without their visual interface?

I love Azure ML studio when I play with my "trial" models, but it would be great if I could store the sequence of the commands as a code on my machine.

I mean whether there is some reference in C# or library in Python that enables to do that? Or is there an API for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can download your experiments into JSON files using Powershell then edit in VS.

```
# Export an Experiment named "xyz" to "MyExp.json"
$exp = Get-AmlExperiment | where Description -eq 'xyz'
Export-AmlExperimentGraph -ExperimentId $exp.ExperimentId -OutputFile 'c:\Temp\MyExp.json'
```

However, there is a major limitation to this cmdlet where any referenced assets by your experiments (aside from AzureML global assets) are NOT included in the exported graph.

Please see here for more information:
https://github.com/hning86/azuremlps#export-amlexperimentgraph